# If you are given two traversal sequences, can you construct the binary tree?

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

What combination of preorder,inorder and postorder Traversal generate a unique binary Tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

following combination can uniquely identify a tree.

Inorder and Preorder.
Inorder and Postorder.
Inorder and Level-order.

And following do not.
Postorder and Preorder.
Preorder and Level-order.
Postorder and Level-order.

For more infomation refer:[Geeksforgeek](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/if-you-are-given-two-traversal-sequences-can-you-construct-the-binary-tree/)

Comment: no problem buddy if you have any such doubts do check them on geeksforgeek first

Comment: Thanks will do that next time

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal):

> The trace of a traversal is called a sequentialisation of the tree.
>   The traversal trace is a list of each visited root node. No one
>   sequentialisation according to pre-, in- or post-order describes the
>   underlying tree uniquely. Given a tree with distinct elements, either
>   pre-order or post-order paired with in-order is sufficient to describe
>   the tree uniquely. However, pre-order with post-order leaves some
>   ambiguity in the tree structure.

Comment: Eugene..i think you got me wrong.the answer nitesh gave was the one i was in search of thanks for your answer.

Comment: Isn't it the same answer?

Comment: earlier you had written the answer is no i thought you said it was not possible

Comment: No. But I can guess. You haven't shown any research effort.